# iFrame Keeps Auto Playing

Tags: iframe, embed, autoplay

I've embedded a video and everytime the page loads the video automatically plays. Ive tried adding ?autoplay=false but it had not effect. Does anyone know how I can stop this video from autoplaying?

```
<script src='http://cnpg.comparenetworks.com/Media/29/Js/z.webinarAnalytics.js' type='text/javascript'></script><iframe width='985' height='675' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='http://cnpg.comparenetworks.com/164137-Large-scale-Computational-and-Empirical-Annotation-of-the-Medicago-truncatula-Metabolome/'></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out, below is the code for the embed. All i had to add was ?autostart=false .

```
<embed src="http://cnpg.comparenetworks.com/164137-Large-scale-Computational-and-Empirical-Annotation-of-the-Medicago-truncatula-Metabolome/?autoStart=false" width="592.5" height="437.5" marginheight="0" scrollbar="no" marginwidth="0"></embed>
```